# How to align one div inside a container and another one align to the right end of browser window?

Tags: html, css, browser, alignment, containers

I have 2 div inside a container, I want to set one div left aligned to the container and another one to be align right end of the browser via css. Is that possible?

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XcBi.jpg)

Some one help me to fix this here fiddle?

```css
.container {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.outer {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.left-box {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  margin-top:20px;
  height:100px;
}

.right-box {
  background: #EC8400;
  padding: 10px 0;
  float:right;
  margin-top:20px;
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="left-box">
      some text
    </div>
    <div class="right-box">
      text/image here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends on your requirements. What should happen when the page or container scrolls? Does any of the divs have to stay locked in its position? Can the divs have a fixed width?

Comment: It's normal page, no need to stay locked in its position. please see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ys5mvjt6/1/
some issues, (image cutoff/scrollbar visible.) What I am expecting is, the right side image need to resize to window size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position fixed and then left 0 for the div you want to align left and right 0 for the one you want to align right. Css will be something like this

```
.divleft {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
}

.divright {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,
first put the div you want right of browser outside container as it really has no point in the div but if you want it inside container, it's still possible.

try this

```
// if the right-box is outside the container
.right-box
{
position: absolute;
right : 0;
}


// if the right-box is inside the container
.right-box
{
position: absolute;
left : 100%;
}
```

**Note**: the second one starts your right-box from extreme right of your container and can be adjusted to your liking.

*similar for the left-box*

Comment: Thanks, some issues in responsive(image cutoff / scrollbar visible), 
https://jsfiddle.net/ys5mvjt6/1/

Comment: make sure all your parent element are containing your child elements properly,

like remove float property or add  `overflow : none`  to parent element
also add  `width :100%`  to your image to fit into the container of it's parent..

here is a clue how to go about your code
https://jsfiddle.net/ys5mvjt6/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=ys5mvjt6

Comment: also you can use this site https://www.w3schools.com/ for more information

Comment: I was checked, no float and overflow. and only container has fixed with, image also 100% width, but still the same issue. https://jsfiddle.net/ys5mvjt6/3/

Comment: can you tell me specifically what is the issue and what is it exactly you want???
to remove the overlapping add `*{overflow:hidden;}` to your css
if you want a scroll add `overflow:scroll` to container
other than that I see no problem

Comment: Thank you for your effort.
I want the "right side image" START from center of the container (like the jsfiddle), and END of the image to be the browser right end. when resizing the browser the image/right-div need to rezise. (my Issue is: If I set overflow:hidden to body the image will cutoff otherwise browser shows scrollbar).